# sum and multiply of multi field for Aggregations in elasticsearch and nest

Tags: asp.net, elasticsearch, nest

I am new to elasticsearch. I use to nest to query data from elasticsearch.

What do i want the way to get result expression of multi fields after aggregations.

example:

```
class public InfoComputer
{
    int Id {get;set;}
    string Name {get;set;}
    int price {get;set;}
    int quantity {get;set;}
};

var result = client.Search<InfoComputer>(s => s
    .Aggregations(a => a
        .Terms("names", st => st
            .Field(o => o.Name)               
            .Aggregations(aa => aa
                .Sum("price", m =>  m
                    .Field(o => o.price)
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

this code only get Sum attribute price.

How can I get `Sum (price * quantity)` with group attribute Name?

Answer (score 2):

In newer versions you need to specify inline in script tag

```
"aggs": {
  "oltotal": {
    "sum": {
      "script": { "inline": "doc['price'].value*doc['amount'].value" } 
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a [scripted sum aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/search-aggregations-metrics-sum-aggregation.html#_script_3):

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "terms_agg": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "name"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sum_agg": {
          "sum": {
            "script": "doc['price'].value * doc['quantity'].value"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think as you think. But i don't see Nest support function Script. If can, can  you   convert elasticsearch into query of NEST?

Answer (score 0):

There is script support in NEST, you can modify your aggregation like this, i.e. by using `Script()` instead of `Field()`:

```
var result = client.Search<InfoComputer>(s => s
    .Aggregations(a => a
        .Terms("names", st => st
            .Field(o => o.Name)               
            .Aggregations(aa => aa
                .Sum("price", m =>  m
                    .Script("doc['price'].value * doc['quantity'].value")
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: I try this code. But allway return is null. i see hit = 0. i think doc['price'].value don't get value

Comment: Can you update your question with some sample documents in your index?